# Extracting numbers with regex in ruby from a numbers divided by a dot (thousand delimiter)

Tags: ruby, regex

Trying to extract '4995' from the string `'4.995,-'` with regex in Ruby.

I tried with

```
/\d+/
```

Which seems to work from this Rubular screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/111c2x0N3s0C

but running it only outputs

```
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm up-voting sawa's answer because it's a good answer.

But since you are new to regular expressions, you may want further explanation as to *why* his answer works for you.

When you are trying to match with the regexp `/\d+/`, what you are saying is "Match for me 1 or more consecutive digits."  But your target string, `4.995,-`, is not made up of only consecutive digits.  It has a `4` and it has a `995`.  The first match of "1 or more consecutive digits" is `4`.  That's why what you're getting as a result is `4`.

Try to look at your problem differently.  Instead of saying, "Find me all the digits and extract those out," you could say, "Find me anything that's *not* a digit, and get rid of it."  To do this, you can use ruby's search-and-replace function, `gsub`.  `gsub` searches a target string for anything that matches a given regular expression, and then it replaces those matches with some replacement string that you also provide.  Documentation on `gsub` can be [found here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)

The regular expression for "non-digit" is `/\D/`.  So, you can do a `gsub` that looks for any `/\D/` and replaces it with a blank string.

```
'4.995,-'.gsub(/\D/,'')
```

Comment: Downside is - `'4.995,-1'.gsub(/\D/,'') # => "49951"`. And `'4.995,-1'.tr("^0-9",'')` also incorrect in that case.But `"4.995,-1"[/\d+.\d+/].tr('.','')` will take its stands as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot match it in a single regex because it is not a single substring.

```
"4.995,-".gsub(/\D/, "") # => "4995"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as below using [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`String#tr`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-tr):

```
"4.995,-"[/\d+.\d+/].tr('.','') # => "4995"
# more Rubyish way using #tr method only
"4.995,-".tr("^0-9",'') # => "4995"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p '4.995,-1'.delete('.')[/\d+/] #=> "4995"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that, like @Arup's solution, works when a digit follows the first non-digit:

```
'4.995,-1'.sub('.','').to_i.to_s #=> "4995"
```

This works because

```
'4.995,-1'.sub('.','') #=> "4995,-1"
```

and `to_i` takes the first part part of a string that can be converted to a Fixnum.

Alternatively:

```
'4.995,-1'.to_f.to_s.sub('.','') #=> "4995"
```

Comment: Thanks! Please explain why this is better than @sawa or arup's solution.

Comment: Andreas, the "best" solution is the one that is most helpful to you. Your choice of @Alvin's answer attests to that. You valued his explanation of sawa's answer more than sawa's answer itself. No problem with that, though others may have chosen differently. If you asked me what I would do, I could answer that: I use use sawa's solution if and only if I were certain there could be no digit after the first non-digit; else I probably would use  hirolau's solution, though Arup's and mine would be OK too. In any event, if you learned something from my answer, I've done my job.